# How to output the json response from Laravel using Jquery ajax (when errors occur)

Tags: javascript, json, laravel, http

I have no problem with the request and response process, Until I try to  parse/process the json data returned from laravel when the error occurs.

I want to display a messsage error when the uploaded file is larger than the system accepts. My action is something like this:

```
...
if($_FILES['file1']['size'] > 0)
  {
    http_response_code(413);
    return Response()->json(["errorMsg" => "Your file is too large!"], 413);


  }
....
```

Client code:

```
  $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/anuncio/realizar_upload_foto",
                 contentType: false,
                cache: false,
                dataType: "JSON",
               processData: false

...

...
    error: function (xh, jso) 

            {


                  alert(jso.errorMsg); //undefined here



                }

            });
```

Comment: you should send message by success method in , because error method run when Ajax requests complete with an error

Comment: @Mohammadb but actually, the Ajax request in the question do complete with an error (`413`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [jQuery.ajax() document](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), the `error` callback accepts 3 parameters:

> **error**
>
> Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

The second parameter (`jso` in your code) is just a String indicating status (`"error"` for example). It does not contain any HTTP response body data.

To get `errorMsg` in the `error` callback, you need to use the first parameter (`jqXHR`). Example code would be:

```
error: function(jqXHR, status, error) {
  var errorObj = jqXHR.responseJSON; // This only works when dataType is defined as "JSON", or the "Content-Type" of HTTP response is "application/json". Otherwise, use the below general code.
  //var errorObj = JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText);

  alert(errorObj.errorMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your way, you should find your data in `xh.responseJSON.errorMsg`

But you should follow REST Api practice.

First of all you should return json code **200** 
and pass your status message like.

```
return response()->json([
    "status" => "success",
    "data" => [....yourdata]
], 200);
```

in error case

```
return response()->json([
    "status" => "error",
    "msg" => "Your file is too large!"
], 4**);
```

Comment: Actually, I think "alway return 200" is not a RESTful API practice. If error happens, the most appropriate status code should be returned.

Comment: @shaochuancs sry, i made mistake. of course it should return errorcode